# Why factoring with quadratic equation gives two different answers?

Tags: quadratics, factoring

I was working on a problem about induction, and I got stuck with a factorization:
$$(2n^2+7n+6)$$
If I find It's roots, I get $x=-2$ and $x=-3/2$. Then I can write it as: $$a(x+2)(x+\frac{3}{2})$$
But how could I find $a$? I don't have a solid background in this topic as I mostly ignored middle school mathematics and now I'm interested in it, been trying to search "how to factor using quadratic formula", the only thing I got right is that if I decide to factor the $2$, I get $(x+2)(2x+3)$ which now is the same parabola. What core topic I'm missing?

Comment: Try setting $x=0$ in both expressions (or rather, $n=0$ in the first and $x=0$ in the second, but I think you mean to have $x=n$.) and solving for $a$.

Comment: The *only* choice for $a$ is for $a$ to be the coefficient of $x^2$.  There nothing more or less to it than that.  In $2n^2 + 7n + 6$ we have the coefficient of $n^2$ is $2$ so $a = 2$.  That's it.  No more.

Comment: " What core topic I'm missing"  that $2x + 3 = 2(x + \frac 32)$.  That's all.  If you can factor by guessing that is fine but if you can't guess you'll have to either complete the square or memorize the quadratic formula.  Is complete the square $2x^2 + 7x + 6=0$ the $2$ just gets in your way so you factor it out.  Divide both sides by two and get $x^2 +\frac 72x + 3 = 0$.  Then continue with completing the square.

Comment: Oh god how blind, thank you all.

Comment: I guess what you are asking about how to recreate the $a$ is:  You don't have to.  The $a$ is completely irrelevant and nobody gives a tinker's patootie what a is.  If $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ then you can multiply or divide both sides by *anything* to get something.  You can divide by $a$ to get rid of the $a$ and $x^2 + \frac bax + \frac ca = 0$.  If you get the two roots and get $(x-r_1)(x-r_2) = x^2 + \frac bax + ca = 0$ and you can multiply both sides by *anything* to get anything.  You can multiply both sides by $a$ but.... who cares?  You don't have to.

Answer (score 2):

If you know how to factor $ax^2 + bx + c$ to $(k_1x + w_1)(k_2x + w_2)$ where $a = k_1k_2$ and $b= k_1w_2 + k_2w_1$ and $c =w_1w_2$ by guessing or using the rational root theorem and guessing, then that's just fine.  You can do that.

And if $ax^2 + bx + c = (k_1x+w_1)(k_2x + w_2) = 0$ then you know that either $k_1x + w_1 =0$ or $k_2x + w_2 = 0$ and if you solve those you get the solutions that either $x = -\frac {w_1}{k_1}$ or $x = -\frac {w_2}{k_2}$.[1]

That is *IF* factoring is easy and obvious and something easy to see.

It's when they are *not* easy and obvious to factor that you need to resort to "completing the square" or using the quadratic equation (which is just a formula for completing the square when you realize that completing the square is the *exact same thing every single time* so you don't need to reinvent the wheel every time and you can just remember the formula).

Then the idea of completing the square is to convert $ax^2 + bx + c=0 \to (x -v)^2 = M$ and therefore we can conclude $x-v =\pm \sqrt M$ and $x = v\pm \sqrt M$.

To do $ax^2 +bx + c=0\to (x-v)^2 = M$ we must first get rid of that stupid $a$ that does nothing be get in the way.  We get rid of it by dividing both sides by $a$ (the assumption is $a \ne 0$.)

$ax^2 + bx + c = 0 \iff  $

$\frac 1a(ax^2 + bx + c) = \frac 1a \cdot 0 \iff$

$x^2 + \frac ba x +\frac ca = 0$.

The next step is to try to get $x^2 +\frac bax + \frac ca=0 \to (x-v)^2 = M$.  Now we know that $(x-v)^2 = x^2 - 2vx + v^2$ so we need to coefficient of $x$ to be $-2v$.  But we have the coefficient of $x$ must be $\frac ba$ so we must have $\frac ba=-2v$.

Okay, but we are jumping ahead of ourselves.

We have $x^2 +\frac ba x + \frac ca = 0 \iff$

$x^2 + \frac bax = -\frac ca$.  Now we want $\frac ba = -2v$ and so we rewrite $\frac ba$ as $2\cdot \frac b{2a}$.

$x^2 + \frac bax = -\frac ca \iff$

$x^2 + 2\cdot \frac b{2a}x = -\frac ca$.

Now we want $(x-v)^2 = x^2 -2vx + v^2$ and we have $x^2 +2\cdot \frac b{2a} x$ but we are missing the $v^2$ term.  But as $v =-\frac b{2a}$ we must have $v^2 = (\frac b{2a}^2$.  So to get that, we add $(\frac b{2a})^2$ to each side.

$x^2 + 2\cdot \frac b{2a} x = -\frac ca \iff$

$x^2 + 2\cdot \frac b{2a} x + (\frac b{2a})^2 = (\frac b{2a})^2 -\frac ca \iff$

$(x + \frac b{2a})^2 = \frac {b^2}{4a^2} -\frac ca \iff$

$(x+\frac b{2a})^2 = \frac {b^2 - 4ac}{4a^2}$.

And we just solve......

$(x+\frac b{2a})^2 = \frac {b^2 - 4ac}{4a^2} \implies$

$x + \frac b{2a} = \pm \sqrt{\frac {b^2 - 4ac}{4a^2}} = \pm\frac {\sqrt{b^2 -4ac}}{2a}\implies $

$x = -\frac b{2a} \pm \frac {\sqrt {b^2-4ac}}{2a} = \frac {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 -4ac}}{2a}$.

Thus we have determined if $ax^2 + bx + c=0$ then the two roots $r_1, r_2$ are $ r_ 1 = \frac {-b + \sqrt{b^2 -4ac}}{2a}$ and $r_2 = \frac {-b - \sqrt{b^2 -4ac}}{2a}$

Now you seem to be asking about getting back to the equation $(x-r_1)(x-r_2) = 0$.

Well, if the two roots are $r_1$ and $r_2$ then EITHER $x=r_1$ or $x = r_2$ and if so then EITHER $x-r_1 = 0$ or $x-r_2 =0$.  In either case we have $(x-r_1)(x-r_2) = 0$ as one of them is zero, so the product of both must be zero.

Now you seem to be asking how we get from $(x-r_1)(x-r_2) = 0$ to $a(x-r_1)(x-r_2)=0$.  We'll the answer to that is we just multiply both sides by $a$.  $(x-r_1)(x-r_2) = 0 \iff a(x-r_1)(x-r_2) = 0$ (assuming $a\ne 0$).  You seem to be asking how do we know what $a$ is.  The answer to that is they *TOLD* us what $a$ was when they gave us $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$.  $a$ is what we were given as the coeficient of $x^2$.

Maybe you are asking if we were given only the roots and $(x-r_1)(x-r_2) = 0$ how would we know what $a$ is.  Well, the answer to that is we *wouldn't*.  And we wouldn't *care*.  $a$ could be have been anything (except $0$) and we just don't care.  After all $(x-r_1)(x-r_2) = 0 \iff a(x-r_1)(x-r_2) = 0;a\ne 0 \iff 58901(x-r_1)(x-r_2) = 0 \iff e^{\sqrt \pi}(x-r_1)(x-r_2) = 0$.

=====

[1] Might be interesting to not that if $a=k_1k_2$ and $b=k_1w_2 + k_2w_1$ and $c =w_1w_2$ then

$x =-\frac {w_1}{k_1}$ would imply

$x = -\frac {w_1k_2}{k_1k_2}=$

$-\frac {b-w_2k_1}{a}=\frac {-b +w_2k_1}{a}=$

$\frac {-b - b+2w_2k_1}{2a}=$

$\frac {-b -\sqrt{(-b+2w_2k_1)^2}}{2a} =$

$\frac {-b -\sqrt{b^2 -4w_2k_1b + 4w_2^2k_1^2}}{2a}=$

$\frac {-b -\sqrt{b^2 - 4w_2k_1(k_1w_2 +k_2w_1)+4w_2^2k_1^2}}{2a}=$

$\frac {-b-\sqrt{b^2 - 4k_1k_2w_1w_2}}{2a} =$

$\frac {-b-\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$

and by similar reasoning $x =-\frac {w_2}{k_2}$ would imply $x = \frac {-b+\sqrt{b^2 -4ac}}{2a}$ so this verifies that the roots are what we expected them to be.

Answer (score 1):

The coefficient $a$ is the coefficient of the degree-2 term, which tells you that $a=2$. Another way to see is evaluating at some point other than zero. For instance if you evaluate both expressions at 1, you get
$$
2+7+6=a\times 3\times \frac52=\frac{15a}2.
$$
This shows that $15=15a/2$ and so $a=2$.